# what is the nature of return in python functions

Tags: python, function, recursion, return

```
def fact(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 2
    return n*fact(n-1)

print(fact(5))
```

I have this code of python function which find the factorial of a given number "n" but I am curious about the behavior of the returns in the function fact() because when I (return 2) in the if statement the answer is double of the factorial and when I add 3 it triples.

Why the return of if condition is multiplied with the return of main function?

My aim is to understand the behavior of more the one return statement in python functions

Comment: Besides that the `n == 0` and `n == 1` cases are wrong, that's basically how [factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial) calculation works.

Comment: And the `return` statement itself isn't magical. When the code hits a `return` statement, the function ends *immediately*. It there's an expression in the statement, its result is what will be returned, otherwise `None` will be returned.

Comment: Notice that there is a *caller* that uses the returned value. Check what it does with that value... I see a multiplication happening with it. Should be no surprise.

Answer (score 0):

Let's go through your code. Using arrows to show recursive calls of functions and their values:

Function calls:
fact(5) -> 5*fact(4) -> 4*fact(3) -> 3*fact(2)->2*fact(1)->1*fact(0)
At fact(0) no further function is called, since the if statement makes it return the value 2 from the if statement return. so fact(0)=2 (which is incorrect, should be 1?)

Then, the values are passed such that (read right to left and compare to function calls above):
fact(5) = 5*4*3*2*1*2 <- 4*3*2*1*2 <- 3*2*1*2<- 2*1*2 <- 1*2
so fact(5) returns 120*2=240.

If you really want this to do the correct mathematical factorial function, fact(0)=1, that is, make the if statement return 1. Then fact(5) will return 120=5!

Answer (score 0):

**When a function calls itself, it is called recursion. This is what you're seeing here.**

In this code, the function `fact` calls itself with the arguments `(n-1)`:

```
def fact(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 2
    return n*fact(n-1)

print(fact(5))
```

Wikipedia defines recursion as:

> In computer science, recursion is a method of solving a computational problem where the solution depends on solutions to smaller instances of the same problem. Recursion solves such recursive problems by using functions that call themselves from within their own code. The approach can be applied to many types of problems, and recursion is one of the central ideas of computer science.

Quoted from: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)

Comment: Please don't quote from the GfG site. Most of it articles, tutorials and other learning materials tend to be flawed, incomplete or sometimes even right out wrong. Please use reputable sites like Wikipedia, or the actual documentation for the language/framework/library.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I wouldn't call Wikipedia "reputable", but I'll change the quote since their definition is a little bit more concise.